# How to use output of get-childitem command

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I wanted to zip the out put of

```
Get-ChildItem -Path E:\test | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
```

i have tried this

```
$command ='Get-ChildItem -Path E:\test | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1';

$file= iex $command
```

and put $file in the zip function but resulted into error .

```
Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\Com\dmp' is denied.
At E:\scripts\last modified folder.ps1:15 char:8
+ $bak = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath #| Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\System32\Com\dmp:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\config' is denied.
At E:\scripts\last modified folder.ps1:15 char:8
+ $bak = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath #| Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\System32\config:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\Configuration' is denied.
At E:\scripts\last modified folder.ps1:15 char:8
+ $bak = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath #| Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\System32\Configuration:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessExcept 
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\ias' is denied.
At E:\scripts\last modified folder.ps1:15 char:8
+ $bak = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath #| Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\System32\ias:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config' is denied.
At E:\scripts\last modified folder.ps1:15 char:8
+ $bak = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath #| Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessExcep 
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Fax\Incoming' is denied.
At E:\scripts\last modified folder.ps1:15 char:8
+ $bak = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath #| Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\Syst...es\Fax\Incoming:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessExcept 
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Fax\Outgoing' is denied.
At E:\scripts\last modified folder.ps1:15 char:8
+ $bak = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath #| Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\Syst...es\Fax\Outgoing:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessExcept 
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Firewall' is denied.
At E:\scripts\last modified folder.ps1:15 char:8
+ $bak = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath #| Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Firewall:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessEx 
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR' is denied.
At E:\scripts\last modified folder.ps1:15 char:8
+ $bak = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath #| Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessExc 
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\WMI' is denied.
At E:\scripts\last modified folder.ps1:15 char:8
+ $bak = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath #| Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\WMI:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessExcepti 
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\MsDtc' is denied.
At E:\scripts\last modified folder.ps1:15 char:8
+ $bak = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath #| Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\System32\MsDtc:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\networklist' is denied.
At E:\scripts\last modified folder.ps1:15 char:8
+ $bak = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath #| Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\System32\networklist:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessExceptio 
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS' is denied.
At E:\scripts\last modified folder.ps1:15 char:8
+ $bak = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath #| Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessExcep 
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\spool\SERVERS' is denied.
At E:\scripts\last modified folder.ps1:15 char:8
+ $bak = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath #| Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\System32\spool\SERVERS:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessExcept 
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\sru' is denied.
At E:\scripts\last modified folder.ps1:15 char:8
+ $bak = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath #| Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\System32\sru:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\Tasks' is denied.
At E:\scripts\last modified folder.ps1:15 char:8
+ $bak = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath #| Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\System32\Tasks:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\wbem\MOF' is denied.
At E:\scripts\last modified folder.ps1:15 char:8
+ $bak = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath #| Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\System32\wbem\MOF:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\wdi' is denied.
At E:\scripts\last modified folder.ps1:15 char:8
+ $bak = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath #| Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\System32\wdi:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\wfp' is denied.
At E:\scripts\last modified folder.ps1:15 char:8
+ $bak = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath #| Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\System32\wfp:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Comment: i don't understand why it is running system32 folder when i mentioned the path e:\test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something missing from your code. As it stands this contains no information about zipping a directory. The root of the issue with the code you are showing is you are asking `Invoke-Expression` to run a folder name. Your $command is returning an object that contains one folder. Was that what you wanted?

You then take that folder object and put it into `Invoke-Expression`. `$file =` means that you mean to put the results of `Invoke-Expression` into `$file`.  I also notice you have the command in single quotes which would mean `Invoke-Expression` would attempt to expand it. More testing is required. I would take a guess that you want to change this up a little.

```
$folder = Get-ChildItem -Path E:\test | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty FullName
```

That would at least return the full folder path that you are looking for. What you are trying to do with it is what i'm lost on. If you have at least DotNet 4.5 you could zip like this example from another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808381/powershell-zip-folder-contents)

```
$folder = Get-ChildItem -Path E:\test | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty FullName
$destination = "e:\test\myZip.zip"
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" )
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($folder, $destination)
```

With [PowerShell Community Extensions](https://pscx.codeplex.com/) you will also find a cmdlet called `Write-Zip` which you could also use

```
Get-ChildItem -Path E:\test | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 | Write-Zip -IncludeEmptyDirectories -OutputPath E:\Test\MyZip.zip
```

If you would prefer: Here is a solution that just uses functionality builtin to PowerShell [Creating a zipped/compressed folder in Windows using Powershell or the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021879/creating-a-zipped-compressed-folder-in-windows-using-powershell-or-the-command-l)