# create zip from script location powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, compression, azure-functions, powershell-cmdlet

I have a PowerShell script which should be able to create a zip of a particular folder, which is also in the same location. But the problem is I do not know where this script will be saved. I tried the code below, but I am not able to do it. The Compress-Archieve method shows the argument is null or empty. Please help.

```powershell
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
$source = Get-ChildItem -Filter -Directory .\PublishOutput
$dest = Get-Location
$f = "\Kovai.zip"
$final = Join-Path $dest $f
Write-Host $final
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($source,$final)
```

Comment: This is a little vague. Do you mean to save the zip in the same location as the folder or in the same location as the script? The answer from @gvee seems to assume same as folder.

Comment: yeah same as the root folder where a sub folder exists which is zipped by the script and also thrown into the root folder itself. @gvee answer is what i was working on . THanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$folderToZip = "C:\FolderToZip"
$rootfolder = Split-Path -Path $folderToZip
$zipFile = Join-Path -Path $rootfolder -ChildPath "ZippedFile.zip"

Write-Output "folderToZip = $folderToZip"
Write-Output "rootfolder  = $rootfolder"
Write-Output "zipFile     = $zipFile"

Compress-Archive -Path $folderToZip -DestinationPath $zipFile -Verbose
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Hi , awesome thanks for the answer . it works fine but only one concern. i want the contents inside FolderToZip to be directly present in the root of zip. Now it does like zip->FolderTozip->Contents . i want it like zip->Contents

Comment: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808381/powershell-zip-folder-contents

Comment: I face the same problem as above

Comment: @HariHaran just change `$folderToZip = "C:\FolderToZip"` to `$folderToZip = "C:\FolderToZip\*"`

Comment: Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to a compressing folder with a subdirectory
[image]

```
 Compress-Archive -PAth test/* -DestinationPath a.zip
 ## replace "test" with your path
```

[image]